# Why won't my refs populate documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose `4.3.6` in a Node.js app.

Say, for example, I have two models:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', SomeParentSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  name: String
}));

var Like = mongoose.model('Like', AnotherParentSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}));
```

I am also using [mongoose-schema-extend](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend), and we can say for the sake of this question that both entities extend from some parent schema.

Since I am using a `ref`, in theory [Model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) should auto-populate the field with a `User` model.

> The ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population

```
Like.findOne({}).populate('user_id').exec(callback);
```

The above just never works. Simple as that (the field ends up as `null`). I have to do this to make it work:

```
Like.findOne({}).populate({ path: 'user_id', model: 'User' }).exec(callback);
```

When I do that, the field is the expected `User` object (but for some reason I had to explicitly tell `populate` to look for that path as a `User` model; even though the `ref` is supposed to handle that, according to the Mongoose docs I linked to above).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I just test your sample codes with following, this query `Like.findOne({}).populate('user_id').exec(callback);` seems work well.

Schema:

```
var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    t: String
}, {collection: 'persons'});

var User = mongoose.model('User', PersonSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  name: String
}));

var ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    s: String
}, {collection: 'parent'});

var Like = mongoose.model('Like', ParentSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}));
```

Insert Data into DB,

```
var user = new User({
    t: 't1',
    _id: '1234567',
    name: 'test'
});

var like = new Like({
    s: 's1',
    _id: '23456789',
});

user.save(function(err, u){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        like.user_id = u._id;
        console.log(like);
        like.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log('save like and user....');
        });
    }
});
```

Query by

```
Like.findOne({}).populate('user_id').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(doc);
});
```

And the result is

```
{ _id: '23456789',
  __t: 'Like',
  user_id: { _id: '1234567', __t: 'User', t: 't1', name: 'test', __v: 0 },
  s: 's1',
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test this. I will look over this answer again shortly and see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @zangw Can you help explain to me the point of population please please. I see in this example in your answer the like collection contains a document with the user in the user_id field, how is this helpful. I asked a question about populate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003893/trying-to-understand-the-use-of-the-populate-method