# Trying to understand the use of the populate method

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-populate, database

I see that one way we use populate is to put one document from another collection into a "parent" collection. I was just going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984199/why-wont-my-refs-populate-documents) question and I was hoping someone could explain the answer to me better. And show me a practical use. Here is an example from the answer.

```
var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    t: String
}, {collection: 'persons'});

var User = mongoose.model('User', PersonSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  name: String
}));

var ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    s: String
}, {collection: 'parent'});

var Like = mongoose.model('Like', ParentSchema.extend({
  _id: String,
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}));
```

Insert Data into DB,

```
var user = new User({
    t: 't1',
    _id: '1234567',
    name: 'test'
});

var like = new Like({
    s: 's1',
    _id: '23456789',
});

user.save(function(err, u){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else {
        like.user_id = u._id;
        console.log(like);
        like.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else
                console.log('save like and user....');
        });
    }
});
```

Query by

```
Like.findOne({}).populate('user_id').exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(doc);
});
```

And the result is

```
{ _id: '23456789',
  __t: 'Like',
  user_id: { _id: '1234567', __t: 'User', t: 't1', name: 'test', __v: 0 },
  s: 's1',
  __v: 0 }
```

QUESTION

1. where does `__t: 'User'` come from?
2. I was thinking that using populate() or ref that would separate the collections but it looks like at the end the like collection has the users document in it. I think I wanted to use populate so I could make a document smaller. 
   3.Also if someone really wanted to help explain this to me I have an example that I have been trying to do and I don't know if I should use populate but if I should it would be great if you show me how. Here is the example.

You have

1. doctors
2. patients
3. information about the practice

There could be like a 1000 doctors and lots of patients for each doctor. and the information will be about their practice(like how many employees they have). so I feel that there should be a separation of concern.(one reason is to prevent a single document for a patient from getting to big). So If we're going with the populate method If you could explain how to set it up for this case. I guess I could have a doctor as a parent and a child  refs for patients and another child refs for information about practice. so maybe there should be an array of objectId for the patients and an array for Other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1: where does __t: 'User' come from?

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend/issues/17).

> mongoose now includes schema inheritance and discriminatorKey functionality that breaks mongoose-schema-extend. mongoose now sets the discriminatorKey schema option to `__t` by default

---

> Q2: I was thinking that using populate() or ref that would separate the collections but it looks like at the end the like collection has the users document in it. I think I wanted to use populate so I could make a document smaller.

It seems you misunderstand the meaning of [`Population`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). There are no joins in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in. Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). So `populate` is not used to make document smaller.

---

> Q3: Doctor, Patient, Practice

Schema could be as following:

```
var DoctorSchema = new Schema ({
   name: String,
   // ... other field
});

var PatientSchema = new Schema ({
  name: String,
  doctor: {type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Doctor'}
});

var PracticeSchema = new Schema ({
  ff: String,
  patientId: {type: Schema.ObjectId,
             ref: 'Patient'},
  doctorId: {type: Schema.ObjectId,
             ref: 'Doctor'}
});
```

As for schema, it is hard to determine which schema is better or not, (with populate or without it). The first thing we should consider is to meet our query requirement, to make the query easy. The design of mongoDB to make the query more efficiently. So our schema should meet it.

Comment: So populate can  help get documents from other collections.I used to have a doctors collection with a long list of patients that involved data and I decided to see if there was a way or if it was worth it to to separate them. I'm coming to see that populate might help with the separation a lil but I don't think it will help with the max data allowed for the collection because populate puts all the documents together So I don't think populate will be useful or me. maybe it will be useful if I want to get access to other collection that I thought I wouldn't need in the past. what do you think?

Comment: @jackblank, you are right. if there are many patients in the doctor, it seems the populate is not right option for you. As we know, the populate just replace `join` operation in mongodb, kind of. also some Query conditions could be applied in the populate operation to find some ref document which we interest.

Comment: @jackblank. Also for mongo schema, it is hard to say which schema is better or not. First of all, the schema we design must meet our requirement to make query more efficient. This is important...